# Is there a way to create a non-copyable aggregate struct in c++20?

Tags: c++, aggregate, c++20

In C++20, aggregates can have no user-declared or inherited constructors (so you can't declare them deleted).
So is there a way have a struct still be an aggregate, but non-copyable?

Comment: Have a non copyable-member?

Comment: The intuition for aggregates is that they don't impose any invariants beyond those of their non-static data members and base classes, so prohibiting copying would not be consistent with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the rules on [aggregates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) you can't have the deleted constructor on the aggregate itself but on a base class e.g.:

```cpp
struct bar{
    // having the defaulted constructor is required for C++20 aggregate initialization to work
    bar() = default;
    // prevents copy and deletes other constructors
    bar(const bar&) = delete;
};

struct foo : bar{
    int a;
};
```

You can then initialize it using aggregate syntax:

```cpp
foo b {{}, 1};

// or

foo c { .a = 1};
```

This will work (mostly) fine: [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/GPjce93PK)

However there are clear tradeoffs as adding inheritance will break some functionality. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/P8Ea61oh3

```cpp
std::optional<foo> e(std::in_place, {}, 1);
```

Will break.

Comment: "*This will work fine*" "Fine" is a relative term. For example, any kind of forwarding (through the ability to use `()` to do aggregate initialization) [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/P8Ea61oh3).

Comment: @NicolBolas fair, but I was going off of the documentation I linked in my first sentence. I didn't even realize that was an option. Also TBF it [Fails](https://godbolt.org/z/abf18G9s9) even when the aggregate is copyable. The type _is an aggregate as best I can tell_. The OP asked for non-copyable... and it is technically both. If you feel that's a deal-breaker I'll delete the answer

Comment: @NicolBolas and GCC and `<type_traits>` concur it is an aggregate https://godbolt.org/z/EM4s5rja8

Comment: I never questioned whether it was an aggregate. But saying that it works "fine" suggests that there are *no* limitations, that it would work in all cases exactly like any other aggregate containing the same members but being copyable (outside of actual copying). And that's just not true. At the very least, you should highlight the limitations that this solution creates.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're nitpicking on something that as I posted in my second godbolt link is an inherent limitation or defect. I cannot be responsible for understanding every library defect available. This is why I generally don't bother to answer questions on SO anymore

Comment: I'm just asking you to *put that in the answer*, not in a comment *beneath* the answer. Make the limitations more prominent.

Comment: @NicolBolas does the edit work? If so let's clean up the comments

Answer (score 6):

Adding a [noncopyable base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074931/2069064) works, but it has the downside that the base is *first*, so it messes with paren initialization. Doing exactly the same idea but putting it *last* is better:

```cpp
struct noncopyable {
    noncopyable() = default;
    noncopyable(noncopyable&&) = default;
    noncopyable& operator=(noncopyable&&) = default;
};

struct foo {
    int i;
    // ... more members here ...
    [[no_unique_address]] noncopyable _ = {};
};
```

---

The paper that removed *any* user-declared constructors from aggregates was [P1008](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf). It's pretty unfortunate that we've basically gone full circle - in C++03, in order to make a class noncopyable, you declared your copy constructor private. In C++11, we made it possible to just delete it explicitly, which makes it more clear in the code what's going on. And in C++20, we removed your ability to do that for aggregates, so now we're back to weird shenanigans.